# Get Pixel Color around an image

Tags: java, pixel

I have an image, and I figured out how to use robot and getPixelColor() to grab the color of a certain pixel. The image is a character that I'm controlling, and I want robot to scan around the image constantly, and tell me if the pixels around it equal a certain color. Is this at all possible? Thanks!

Comment: Myself, I'd use the Robot to extract the image that's just a little larger than the "character", and then analyze the BufferedImage obtained. The details of course will depend on the details of your program. Probably the quickest would be to get the BufferedImage's Raster, then get thats dataBuffer, then get thats data, and analyze the array returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Myself, I'd use the Robot to extract the image that's just a little larger than the "character", and then analyze the BufferedImage obtained. The details of course will depend on the details of your program. Probably the quickest would be to get the BufferedImage's Raster, then get thats dataBuffer, then get thats data, and analyze the array returned.

For example,

```
// screenRect is a Rectangle the contains your "character" 
// + however many images around your character that you desire
BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
int[] imgData = ((DataBufferInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

// now that you've got the image ints, you can analyze them as you wish.
// All I've done below is get rid of the alpha value and display the ints.
for (int i = 0; i < screenRect.height; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < screenRect.width; j++) {
    int index = i * screenRect.width + j;
    int imgValue = imgData[index] & 0xffffff;
    System.out.printf("%06x ", imgValue );
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```